# JavaScript event loop: why is my click function executed before other tasks in the queue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-loop

As far as I know, the JavaScript event queue gets populated by browser events like `click` or delayed functions like `setTimeout`. The event loop will then continuously check the current call stack and if it is empty, it will execute the first task in the queue until that one finished completely. After that, the next task in the queue will get executed and so on.

So I thought that the following function should populate the queue with 1000 `delay` functions:

```
function run() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    setTimeout(delay, 0);
  }
}
```

That would mean that are now 1000 functions on the queue. And if delay will take some time to execute, this should block the queue for quite a while. But as you can see in the provided snippet that doesn't seem to be true (click the "Do Many!" button first, which will start the timeouts, then click the "Do Once!" button and see it working as well)

So even though I added all those functions to the queue, I can still click a button and the `click` event handler will still be executed in between, despite the fact that it was added to the queue later. Why is that the case?

```js
$(function () {
  $("#do-many").click(run);
  $("#do-once").click(single);
});

var counter = [0,0];


function run() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    setTimeout(delay, 0);
  }
}

function delay() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    
  }
  update(0);
}

function single() {
  update(1);
}

function update(idx) {
    counter[idx] += 1;
    $("#c" + idx).text("Count " + idx + ": " + counter[idx]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="do-once">Do Once!</button>
 <button id="do-many">Do Many!</button>
 <div id="c0"></div>
 <div id="c1"></div>
```

Comment: It would not be at all unreasonable for browsers to prioritize the handling of events caused by user activity over timers.

Comment: `delay()` does absolutely nothing 10000000 times, then it calls `update(0)` once. Is `delay()` a congressman?

Comment: @Pointy It sounds reasonable, yes. I guess that means, that there would be multiple event queues then?

Comment: Try your test in Firefox. For me (in Firefox), the timers block the click response.

Comment: @Pointy You're right. Firefox doesn't even render the page in between the `delay` functions. So I guess that is something that differs heavily from browser to browser.